# How to connect a cursor motion signal to a function (GTK)

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3, gdk

I'm writing a C program using the GTK libraries that reads the position of the cursor and writes it out to another function.  I've written code that's able to accurately read the cursor position data, but I can't figure out how to connect a cursor motion event to a function.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    GdkWindow *window;
    GtkWidget *gtk_window;
    GdkDevice *mouse;
    gint x = 0;
    gint y = 0;

    gdk_init(&argc, &argv);
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);


    gtk_window=gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_widget_show(gtk_window);    
    window = gtk_widget_get_window(GTK_WIDGET(gtk_window));

    gdk_window_maximize(window);
    gdk_window_set_title(window, "write-mouse");

    GdkSeat *seat = gdk_display_get_default_seat (gdk_display_get_default ());
    mouse = gdk_seat_get_pointer (seat);

    gdk_window_get_device_position (window, mouse, &x, &y, NULL);

    //read cursor position at startup to test code
    g_print("X = %d\n", x);
    g_print("Y = %d\n", y);

    //g_signal_connect (mouse, "something?", G_CALLBACK (print_mouse), NULL);

    gtk_main();
}

static void print_mouse(GdkDevice *mouse, gpointer data){
    gint x = 0;
    gint y = 0;
    //do I need to pass the window object to "print_mouse" function too?
    //can I point to it using some gtk function?
    gdk_window_get_device_position (window, mouse, &x, &y, NULL);

    g_print("X = %d\n", x);
    g_print("Y = %d\n", y);
}
```

I assume I need to use "g_signal_connect()" to connect the cursor motion event to the "print_mouse" function, but I can't figure out what to put as the arguments to make it work.

What should I put in the "detailed_signal" field of "g_signal_connect()?

Is there a better way to do this entirely?

Answer (score 0):

your something is "motion-notify-event" which gives data as a GdkEventMotion event: https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-motion-notify-event

I think you will also need to ensure to gtk_widget_add_events(widget, GDK_POINTER_MOTION_MASK); when constructing the widget. For performance reasons you may want to set this up to only run code at a certain refresh rate so as not too overburden the cpu.

Comment: Thanks. This is getting me closer, but I can't get the gtk_widget_add_events() to work.  When I add the line "gtk_widget_add_events(mouse, GDK_POINTER_MOTION_MASK);", it won't compile because "mouse" is not a GtkWidget.  It's a GdkDevice.  When I to cast it as a GtkWidget with the code "gtk_widget_add_events(GTK_WIDGET(mouse), GDK_POINTER_MOTION_MASK);", it complies, but throws an invalid cast error when I run it.  Is there another function for adding events to GdkDevices as opposed to GtkWidgets?

Comment: You need to add events to the `gtk_window` not mouse: `gtk_widget_add_events(gtk_window, GDK_POINTER_MOTION_MASK);`

Comment: Ok.  So how do I pass the pointer object to the callback function?  Do I pass it as the "gpointer data" argument?  When I pass the mouse object `g_signal_connect (gtk_window, "motion-notify-event", G_CALLBACK (print_mouse), mouse)`, I can sucessfully pass it to the callback function, but I get a segmentation fault when I try to read the position `GdkDevice *mouse = data;
 gdk_device_get_position(mouse, NULL, &x, &y);`

Comment: You won't need the mouse object. In fact I don't believe you would ever have reason to use it at the UI layer. There's also no guarantee you have a mouse device given gtk's accessibility constructs.

Comment: Use the GdkEventMotion to get the location.

Comment: Also you may want to use gtype's type casting eg GTK_WIDGET(window) to get run time checking to aid debugging and unit tests rather than doing implicit casts (like with GdkDevice*)

Comment: The callback function has GdkEvent as its second parameter

Comment: Thanks.  How do I use the GdkEventMotion structure to get the location.  I see that it contains x and y variable, but how do I access the structure?  Is it passes to the callback function as a GdkEvent?  Could you provide some sample code showing how to read the GdkEventMotion in the callback function?

Comment: We are now at the point where reading the documentation should answer all questions re: the finer details. In this case the pointer is actually a GdkEventMotion under the hood so all you need to do is to cast the pointer, but GdkEvent should be sufficient for your needs here. It has members x and y.